# How to get the textfield which causes a NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtextfield, numberformatexception

I want to change the border of a text field which caused a `NumberFormatException`:

```
try {
   input1 = Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText());
   input2 = Integer.parseInt(textfield2.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
    setBorderBorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2,2,2,2,Color.red);
}
```

How do I now get the text field in the catch clause which causes the `NumberFormatException` in order to change the color of the border?

Comment: You are missing some closing brackets.

Comment: POst your error log??

Comment: thanks for quick answers. for example someone put an illegal number format in textfield1. I want to change the border of just this textfield in order to show where the false input was made

Comment: @Subburaj no error log. The OP wants to know which text box to highlight if there's an error.

Comment: Use a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` and the entire problem is solved.

Comment: @user2993610 please note how the community changed your question to make it more concise.

Comment: or use JFormattedTaextField with DocumentListener and Borders, then idea to chatch any exception can be useless

Comment: @Andrew Thompson H.N.Y. 2014

Comment: @mKorbel  Same to you.  Hope you have a great one.  :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thank you, but I have to wait 9 and one half hour

Answer (score 5):

I advise you to surround each statement with `try-catch`:

```
try{
eingabe1 = Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) { /* Exception from textfield1 */ }
try {
eingabe2 = Integer.parseInt(textfield2.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) { /* Exception from textfield2 */}
```

When you put many statements in a `try` block, you usually handle the *exception* that happened in the same way, independently from the *object* that caused the *exception*.

Comment: +1 sound like exactly what the OP is looking for. Surprised you understood. I sure didn't :)

Comment: If you got more than a few inputs to parse, you may want to create a little helper method which does this without the duplication.

Comment: @downvoter, please mention the reason so I can learn from my mistakes, the downvote is meaningless without a reason.

Comment: i thought about this solution but i think its not ideal if you have many textfields. there has to be another solution...

Answer (score 1):

Place your code for performing that special operation and its error handling in separate method:

```
private int parseAndHandleException(JTextField textfield) {
    int eingabe;
    try {
        eingabe = Integer.parseInt(textfield.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       ...setBorderBorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2,2,2,2,Color.red));
    }
    return eingabe;
}
```

and then call like this:

```
eingabe1 = parseAndHandleException(textfield1);
eingabe2 = parseAndHandleException(textfield2);
```

Comment: This is closer the the OPs requirements, since there is less duplication (+1).

Answer (score 0):

its seems you forgot ")"

```
eingabe1 = Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText());
eingabe2 = Integer.parseInt(textfield2.getText());
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question.

Comment: It's obvious that that the code in OP is just a pseudo code and it may contain errors. The question is not about compile errors I think, but about finding which TextFiled is having an invalid input which is causing a NumberformatException.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use JSlider, like the code below, to get rid of `NumberFormatException`.

```
        int minValue = 0;
        int maxValue = 100;
        int defultValue = 10;
        JSlider s = new JSlider(minValue, maxValue, defultValue);
        s.setLabelTable(s.createStandardLabels(10));
        s.setMinorTickSpacing(2);
        s.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        s.setPaintTicks(true);
        s.setPaintLabels(true);
```

To get the value of the `JSlider`, call the method `getValue()` that return always an integer.